# cant open https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B282PN5SHvjiVzlCeDd4V3l2Nm8/view in webview

Tags: android, webview, drive

I have made a hyperlink which link a image to this address: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B282PN5SHvjiVzlCeDd4V3l2Nm8/view . Basically this link leads to a video in google drive, i am able to play and load this file in chrome(both on pc and mobile) but unable to load it on webview. It only shows a blank screen whenever i click on the hyperlink. So how could i load it on webview ?
Thanks in Advance!
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can download content of that file by means of changing it's http address to

```
String fileId = httpLink.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "").split("/")[0];
newHttpLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId;
```

and getting InputStream from this `newHttpLink`:

```
InputStream is = new URL(newHttpLink).openStream();
```